# Rails: How to retrieve database credentials to install ForestAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forestadmin

I want to install [ForestAdmin](https://www.forestadmin.com/) to my Rails development app. Using `Rails.configuration.database_configuration`, I can get the following info:

> {"default"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000},
>   "development"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000,
>   "database"=>"db/development.sqlite3"}, "test"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3",
>   "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/test.sqlite3"},
>   "production"=>{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000,
>   "database"=>"db/production.sqlite3"}}

Unfortunately, when following [the steps using NPM install](https://www.forestadmin.com/), I get the following error:

> SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

How can I get the user/password of the database and its port? Is the application port 3310?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a SQLite database configured for your Rails app but are using a MySQL database in your Forest admin ?

Comment: Indeed, I thought it would be compatible as Forest Admin doesn't have any SQLite option...

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by switching to postgres.